# Pattern - Leave 1st instance of 1st column and replace others

Tags: perl, bash, unix

**Input :**

```
    Process1 |5f|03/29/13 15:32:59
    Process1 |6f|03/29/13 17:59:03
    Pro cess1 |s7|03/29/13 17:59:05
    Pro cess1 |1234|03/29/13 20:33:43
    Pro cess1 |L|03/29/13 20:33:54
    A Pro cess |45g|03/29/13 20:34:59
    A Pro cess |f4|03/29/13 21:10:22
    B Pro cess |Es|03/30/13 00:11:25
    B Pro cess |23|03/30/13 00:47:20
    B Pro cess |E23|03/30/13 01:03:07
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Process1 |5f|03/29/13 15:32:59
 |6f|03/29/13 17:59:03
Pro cess1|s7|03/29/13 17:59:05
 |1234|03/29/13 20:33:43
 |L|03/29/13 20:33:54
A Pro cess |45g|03/29/13 20:34:59
 |f4|03/29/13 21:10:22
B Pro cess |Es|03/30/13 00:11:25
 |23|03/30/13 00:47:20
 |E23|03/30/13 01:03:07
```

**Logic :** Leave only one instance of 1st column and replace other instance with blank

I tried this, but didnt work(Taking below code in loop) :

```
sed -e 's/Process1/ /g' -e 's/ /Process1/1' Input
```

(Replace Process1 with '-' and then replace 1st instance of '-' with Process1 again.

As given by "cnicutar" , i modified the awk as  :

awk -F "|" '{a[$1]++; if (a[$1] > 1) $1=""; print;}' File

**Output from abv :**

```
Process1 |5f|03/29/13 15:32:59
 6f 03/29/13 17:59:03
Pro cess1 |s7|03/29/13 17:59:05
 1234 03/29/13 20:33:43
 L 03/29/13 20:33:54
A Process |45g|03/29/13 20:34:59
 f4 03/29/13 21:10:22
B Pro cess |Es|03/30/13 00:11:25
 23 03/30/13 00:47:20
 E23 03/30/13 01:03:07
```

**Desired Output (insert |)**

```
Process1 |5f|03/29/13 15:32:59
     |6f|03/29/13 17:59:03
Pro cess1 |s7|03/29/13 17:59:05
     |1234|03/29/13 20:33:43
     |L|03/29/13 20:33:54
A Process |45g|03/29/13 20:34:59
     |f4|03/29/13 21:10:22
B Pro cess |Es|03/30/13 00:11:25
     |23 | 03/30/13 00:47:20
     |E23| 03/30/13 01:03:07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a slightly lateral solution:

```
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ awk '{a[$1]++; if (a[$1] > 1) $1=""; print;}' file
Process1 |5f|03/29/13 15:32:59
 |6f|03/29/13 17:59:03
 |s7|03/29/13 17:59:05
 |1234|03/29/13 20:33:43
 |L|03/29/13 20:33:54
AProcess |45g|03/29/13 20:34:59
 |f4|03/29/13 21:10:22
BProcess |Es|03/30/13 00:11:25
 |23|03/30/13 00:47:20
 |E23|03/30/13 01:03:07
```

---

In light of edit, you might want:

```
awk -F'|' '{OFS="|"; a[$1]++; if (a[$1] > 1) $1=" "; print;}' file
```

Comment: This is gr8 ... Just edited my input ... apologies for not producing the right input at first go....

Comment: @Chronicles Okay, I edited the answer. You may need to fiddle with the whitespace though.